# How can I humanely kill a stranded Kerbal?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

So I've got a stranded kerbal in sun orbit with no fuel or resources except for the EVA jetpack. I'm playing Demo, so there is absolutely no hope of me bringing him home in a rescue mission (docking parts not availble). I have honestly no idea how I ended up stuck in sun orbit anyways (a failed moon landing attempt).

I think the most humane thing to do in this situation would be to end the little green guy's life quickly so he doesn't have to spend infinite years alone and stuck in a capsule. How can I kill this Kerbal in my current situation?

PS: Preferably a humane way that does it quick, but I won't be too picky so if it isn't I don't mind.

Comment: I didn't realize that a Kerbal could live infinitely. Also won't he run out of food and water?

Comment: @Dragonrage yeah apparently they can. I looked it up. They are green because they got chlorphyll and produce there own food. They hibranate or something so they can live forever. Sources: [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174663/do-kerbals-die-of-natural-causes)

Comment: Well, if he hibernating, then he can sleep peacefully right through the end of the world, but is there like any type of missile you can shoot at him or something?

Comment: @Dragonrage lol true. I still feel bad though xD. Don't think I could build an accurate enough missile with enough thrust to get to him in Demo. I do intend to buy the game but I can't do it this week or next so you know...

Comment: Why don't you just send a rocket up with two command capsules on it? He can leave his rocket and get in the new one.

Comment: @SaintWacko true. Problem is like I said before: this is demo. Don't think I could really build a good enough rocket that can go all the way there and come all the way back.. Hell I can hardly get into orbit around kerbin. Me getting to sun orbit was a crazy accident caused by time speeding up by max

Comment: ... and +1 for caring.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most humane way to end his agony is to **terminate the mission** in the Tracking Station. To do it, follow this procedure:

1. Go to the Tracking Station.

   [image: Tracking station]
2. Make sure the astronauts are marked to be shown on screen. It they aren't, just click the astronaut icon on the top of the screen.

   [image: Tracking station icon bar]
3. Select the aforementioned kerbal from the list of objects or click it on the main screen.
4. Click the <kbd>Terminate</kbd> button on the lower left panel.

   [image: Lower panel where the terminate button is]
5. A popup window will appear asking you to confirm the action.

   [image: Confirmation popup window]
6. Click <kbd>Terminate</kbd> to confirm that you want to terminate the mission and kill (humanely) all kerbals on board.

This method is quick and painless (at least for you) and it helps remove clutter (sorry - no offense) from the list of managed objects.

Seriously, any other way to terminate this kerbal is just cruelty.

Besides, space administration is *business*. Get over it.

Comment: LOL great answer. Its okay that it was "obvious", I didn't know that you could do this! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! At first, I thought this was obvious, but now I realize it isn't at all, so I removed the corresponding remark.